# Bidirectional WebSockets in laravel?

Tags: node.js, laravel, sockets, websocket, phpwebsocket

Anyone here familiar with bi-directional WebSockets in laravel?
Please note I am not talking about pusher+echo. pusher+echo cannot make a request to the server. 
I have experience in express.js in which the socket can listen at server side. 
I am looking for a similar feature.. any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I use Laravel Broadcasting with Laravel Websockets and Laravel Echo for server to client communication while using the code below for client to server communication using websockets api. Big thanks to [Acadea.io](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUlbN_xsdXg). Please refer to the following:

BaseSocketHandler.php

```
namespace App\Websockets\SocketHandler;

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\App;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\QueryParameters;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Exceptions\UnknownAppKey;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\MessageComponentInterface;

abstract class BaseSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected function verifyAppKey(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        $appKey = QueryParameters::create($connection->httpRequest)->get('appKey');
        if (!$app = App::findByKey($appKey)) {
            throw new UnknownAppKey($appKey);
        }
        $connection->app = $app;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function generateSocketId(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        $socketId = sprintf('%d.%d', random_int(1, 1000000000), random_int(1, 1000000000));
        $connection->socketId = $socketId;

        return $this;
    }

    function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        dump('on opened');
        $this->verifyAppKey($conn)->generateSocketId($conn);
    }

    function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        dump('closed');
    }

    function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        dump($e);
        dump('onerror');
    }
}
```

CustomSocketHandler

```
namespace App\Websockets\SocketHandler;

use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\MessageComponentInterface;

class CustomSocketHandler extends BaseSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface
{

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onOpen() method.
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onClose() method.
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $connection, \Exception $e)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onError() method.
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $connection, MessageInterface $msg)
    {
        $body = json_decode(collect(json_decode($msg->getPayload(), true)), true);
        $access_token =  $body["access_token"];
        $authenticateUserByAccessToken = new AuthenticateUserByAccessToken();
        $chat_user = $authenticateUserByAccessToken->getAuthenticatedUser($access_token);

        // TODO: Implement onMessage() method.
        
        $dataToBeReturned = json_encode($dataToBeReturned);
        $connection->send($dataToBeReturned);
    }
```

web

```
use App\Websockets\SocketHandler\CustomSocketHandler;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Facades\WebSocketsRouter;

WebSocketsRouter::webSocket('/socket/custom-socket-url', CustomSocketHandler::class);
```

JS

```
function functionName(access_token, id) {
    const socket = new WebSocket(
        `wss://${window.location.hostname}:${process.env.MIX_LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT}/socket/custom-socket-url?appKey=${process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY}`
    );

    socket.onopen = function (event) {
        // console.log("on open", event);
    };

    socket.onclose = function (event) {
        // console.log("on close", event);
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        // console.log("on message", event);
    };

    socket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
            access_token: access_token, //optional JWT Auth Token
            payload: {
                id: id,
            },
        })
    );
    socket.close();
}
```

Optional. If you want to authenticate your websocket connection (using jwt)

```
namespace App\Websockets\SocketHandler;

use App\Models\AuthenticationModelToBeUsed;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class AuthenticateUserByAccessToken
{
    public function getAuthenticatedUser($access_token)
    {
        Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', AuthenticationModelToBeUsed::class);
        try {
            JWTAuth::setToken($access_token);
            if (!$user = JWTAuth::toUser($access_token)) {
                return response()->json(array('message' => 'user_not_found'), 404);
            }
        } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {
            return response()->json(array('message' => 'token_expired'), 404);
        } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {
            return response()->json(array('message' => 'token_invalid'), 404);
        } catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(array('message' => 'token_absent'), 404);
        }

        Log::info($user);
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the laravel events method along with [socketIO](https://socket.io/) (as discussed in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51)

In this method you could emit messages back to socket server, or you could initiate an XHR request to directly interact with the backend server (server with laravel).

Comment: i can always call an XHR service to communicate to the server but that's slow. thats where socket comes to place. this is super easy in node.js if you know node.js you know what iam talking about

Comment: No, I didn't mean the http polling, instead initiate the xhr requests only when there is a socket handshake is received. So I guess the server requests will be minimal and will be happening only when it's required.

Comment: iam taking a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events now. will ping here if i got a grab on something

Comment: in my case the api is very frequent, something like a double tick and blue tick in whatsapp. i really need a socket api here

Comment: let me take a look at event and let you know

Comment: Using laravel events you could send the message to redis db and you can make use of [pub/sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) feature in your socket server to read these messages.